# Issues in set background for input of form in table

Tags: html, css

I have created ASP page, which looks like:
[image]

I need something like this center image:
[image]

I tried to set background for header, it works fine. However, I am not able to set for next button.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {

        // CREATE A "DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING JQUERY ".css()" CLASS.
        var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding: '5px', margin: '20px', width: '170px'});

        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb1" value="Text Element 1" />');
        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb2" value="Text Element 2" />');
        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb3" value="Text Element 3" />');
        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb4" value="Text Element 4" />');
        $('#main').after(container);   // ADD BOTH THE DIV ELEMENTS TO THE "main" CONTAINER.

        var iCnt = 4;

        $('#btAdd').click(function() {
            if (iCnt <= 19) {

                iCnt = iCnt + 1;

                // ADD TEXTBOX.
                $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
                            'value="Text Element ' + iCnt + '" />');


                $('#main').after(container);   // ADD BOTH THE DIV ELEMENTS TO THE "main" CONTAINER.
            }
            else {      // AFTER REACHING THE SPECIFIED LIMIT, DISABLE THE "ADD" BUTTON. (20 IS THE LIMIT WE HAVE SET)
                
                $(container).append('<label>Reached the limit</label>'); 
                $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable'); 
                $('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            }
        });

        $('#btRemove').click(function() {   // REMOVE ELEMENTS ONE PER CLICK.
            if (iCnt != 0) { $('#tb' + iCnt).remove(); iCnt = iCnt - 1; }
        
            if (iCnt == 0) { $(container).empty(); 
        
                $(container).remove(); 
                $('#btSubmit').remove(); 
                $('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt') 

            }
        });

        $('#btRemoveAll').click(function() {    // REMOVE ALL THE ELEMENTS IN THE CONTAINER.
        
            $(container).empty(); 
            $(container).remove(); 
            $('#btSubmit').remove(); iCnt = 0; 
            $('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled'); 
            $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt');

        });
    });

    // PICK THE VALUES FROM EACH TEXTBOX WHEN "SUBMIT" BUTTON IS CLICKED.
    var divValue, values = '';

    function GetTextValue() {

        $(divValue).empty(); 
        $(divValue).remove(); values = '';

        $('.input').each(function() {
            divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
                padding:'5px', width:'200px'
            });
            values += this.value + ','
        });

        $(divValue).append('<p><b>Your selected values</b></p>' + values);
        $('body').append(divValue);

    }
```

```css
#tbl-two-columns td.invitation-col2
 {
  padding-left:0px !important;
 
 }
 .cs_pendingInvitation img
 {
  margin-top:3px;
 }
 
 // styles for invite more friends -- selva
 
 .invitation-header
 {
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #C2EBFF;
  z-index: 99;
 }
 #btAdd
 {
  color: #00BFFF;
 }
#main a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
    
input#nextbutton {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #00BFFF;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 0px none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.input {
    color: #333;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 380px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tblmain atep" style="width: 450px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
   
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="tdbodycontent" align="left">
<table class="wrapper" style="width:450px;margin:0 auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td class="tdcontainer" align="left">

<table style="width:450px;" id="tbl-two-columns" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <th class="invitation-header" valign="top"> <!-- th added for invite header --selva -->
       Help make your neighborhood safer, Invite friends and family
                                    </th> <!-- END - th added for invite header --selva -->
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="invitation-col2" valign="top">
<table id="tab1" class="tab-container" style="width:400px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td valign="top">
<form method="post" name="form1" action="invitation_enrollv5.asp?action=1" onsubmit="return GetTextValue()">

                                                    <!--START - Invite Buttons - Selvarani-->
                                                    <div style="padding: 5px; margin: 0px;"><input class="input" id="tb1" placeholder="Email" type="text"><input class="input" id="tb2" placeholder="Email" type="text"><input class="input" id="tb3" placeholder="Email" type="text"><input class="input" id="tb4" placeholder="Email" type="text"></div><div id="main"><a style="float: right;" href="#" id="btAdd" value="" class="bt">Invite more friends</a></div><table style="margin: 0px auto 10px; width: 350px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <input id="contact_list" name="contact_list" value="" type="hidden">
                                                    <!--END - Invite Buttons - Selvarani-->
                                                    </table>
                                                    <p style="">Invite from my address book</p>
                                                    <img src="Web5/images/invite-your-contacts.png" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Invite your contacts" onclick="InviteBoxClick();"><br>
                                                    <a href="#cs_container" data-cs-init="true" class="cs_import">
                                                    </a>
                                                
                                                    <input name="cnote" value="" type="hidden">
                                                    <input name="pkfamilyinvite" value="0" type="hidden">
                                                        <input name="vn" value="0" type="hidden">
                                                      <input name="gORn" value="1" type="hidden"><br>
                                                    <input style="float: right;" id="nextbutton" name="" value="Next" type="submit"> <!-- id="nextbutton" added for button styles -- selva -->
                                                    
                                                    </form>
                                                                    </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                                         </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                                                                     </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdfooter" align="left">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `input#nextbutton {` with `#nextbutton {`

Comment: Not like that, background of button is working.. i need background for button like my posted image.. thanks.

Comment: can you please attach image, i can't able to open the image url.